# Highlight cells in a column the same as the cells directly above them

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VLOOKUP formula in a macro to highlight cells in a list of item #'s (Column B).  In the cells directly below each item are the item descriptions. What I need to do is if an item # gets highlighted, then copy the same highlighting for it's description directly below it.

```
Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=VLOOKUP(B1:B3000,Sheet1!$A:$A,1,FALSE)"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: Can you share the vlookup formula you're using?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(B1:B3000,Sheet1!$A:$A,1,FALSE)

Comment: The VLOOKUP works as expected.  It highlights the item # if it was found.  What I need is the item #'s description also to be highlighted.

Comment: Original post was updated.

Comment: For each item, is the description confined to just the one cell directly beneath it, or can there be multiple cells?

Comment: If VLOOKUP finds a matching Item #, it highlights that cell.  The Item Description is in the cell directly beneath it, which needs highlighted and is not duplicated elsewhere.  If an Item # is not found by VLOOKUP then that Item # is not highlighted and therefore the Item Description doesn't need highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'd use `ISNUMBER` and `MATCH` instead of `VLOOKUP`, like this: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,Sheet1!A:A,0))`.
2. With relative references, and changing the "Applies to" range, you can highlight the description with a similar formula. E.g. in the following example, the formula is `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,Sheet1!A:A,0))`, but the  "Applies to" range is `B3:B12`, effectively applying the highlighting to the cell immediately under the item number.

[image]

The VBA should be pretty easy to figure out here.

Comment: But the Item Description is not located on Sheet1, the description is only listed in active worksheet, so there is no description to match on Sheet1.

Comment: The rule works because it looks up the *item number*, not the description... there's a one-row offset between the formula and the "Applies to" range, so the highlighting gets applied to the description even though it's the *item number* that matches.

Comment: Cool! I think I might use this actually in the future, so thanks for asking the question! Glad to help out and happy coding.